# MIGX TV not working on MODX Revolution 2.4.0

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, migx

I have installed MIGX TV on MODX Revolution 2.4.0, but after installing it when i try to create new TVs in input type i dont get MIGX ?

[image]

Should i switch back to older version of MoDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you scroll to the bottom of that Input Type list? I think the MIGX option is at the bottom rather than inserted in alphabetical order.

Also, I'm pretty sure I just read somewhere that MIGX is not yet compatible with 2.4.0... but don't quote me. You might ask directly on the MODX forums - use the [MIGX board](http://forums.modx.com/board?board=271).

Comment: Sorry title was wrong it didnt work in version 2.3.6 after update all is ok

Comment: You might want to change the text of your question for the sake of others' searching.